# PythonのUDP通信で更新周期の違うコードからラグなしのデータを受け取る方法

Tags: python, network, socket, udp

Qiitの、[Pythonで一定間隔ごとにループを回す方法](https://qiita.com/montblanc18/items/05715730d99d450fd0d3)と、[UDP通信](https://qiita.com/akakou/items/e9fbcfc0c69cc957152e)の記事を参考にしています。

以下のudpSend.pyは、0.1秒ごとにデータを送信するコードです。

**udpSend.py**

```
import time
import threading
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

HOST = ''
PORT = 5000
ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1" # 自分に送信

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
startTime = time.time()

def worker():
    try:
        msg = str(time.time()-startTime)
        s.sendto(msg.encode(), (ADDRESS, PORT))
        time.sleep(8)
    except:
        pass

def scheduler(interval, f, wait = True):
    base_time = time.time()
    next_time = 0
    while True:
        t = threading.Thread(target = f)
        t.start()
        if wait:
            t.join()
        next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
        time.sleep(next_time)

scheduler(0.1, worker, False)
```

そして、以下のudpRecv.pyは1.0秒ごとにudpを受信してprintするコードになっています。

**udpRecv.py**

```
import time
import threading
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

HOST = ''   
PORT = 5000

# ソケットを用意
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
# バインドしておく
s.bind((HOST, PORT))

def worker():
    try:
        msg, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
        print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
        time.sleep(8)
    except:
        pass

def scheduler(interval, f, wait = True):
    base_time = time.time()
    next_time = 0
    while True:
        t = threading.Thread(target = f)
        t.start()
        if wait:
            t.join()
        next_time = ((base_time - time.time()) % interval) or interval
        time.sleep(next_time)

scheduler(1, worker, False)
```

送信側は0.1秒間隔なのに対し、受信側は1.0秒間隔でデータを受信させたところ
以下のような出力結果になりました。

```
10.801141023635864
10.900874853134155
11.001609802246094
11.10069465637207
11.200777292251587
11.301504135131836
```

udpRecv.pyによって、1秒間隔で値がprintされるのに
printされる時間は0.1秒間隔の値になっており、ラグが発生してしまっています。

送信側の時刻と、受信側の時刻で一定以上のラグがあった場合
その送信データは受け取らないようなことは出来ないのでしょうか？

udpRecv.pyで、1.0秒ごとの値を受け取って1.0秒ごとにをprintしたいです。

Comment: 受信側で、秒が変わるまで送信データを読み捨てるのは問題がありますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 受信側は1.0秒間隔でデータを受信させたところ

この認識が誤っていて、「1秒間隔で受信バッファに溜まっているデータを読み出す」コードが正しい動きをしています

本当にやらないといけないことは質問からはよみとれませんが、例えば

- 最新(もしくは必要なタイムスタンプ)のデータ以外は読み捨て
- n + 0.9秒でバッファを捨てて0.1秒後に読み出し

などする必要があります